# Who was feeding Zeus the dog while Cecilia was away from the mansion?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-invisible-man-2020

In the 2020 movie *The Invisible Man*, after Adrian is declared dead, Cecilia, over a course of an unknown time period,

- visits a lawyer to settle her inheritance
- celebrates her freedom with Sydney and her dad James
- prepares and goes to a job interview and passes out
- visits the same lawyer again with James to discuss Adrian's fake suicide
- struggles with the invisible man for the first time and flees in a stranger's car

Then she goes to Adrian's mansion and discovers their dog Zeus is still there.

Who has been feeding this dog since Adrian's death? She does not look surprised at all when she meets the dog in an empty mansion with all the furniture covered.

Comment: There may be mansion caretaker, also to handle the garden

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cecilia isn't surprised to find the dog still there because she knows Adrian is still alive.  She knows he is the invisible man.  She goes to the house to look for evidence that he has the technology to become invisible - to confirm what she already knows.

Maybe Adrian still lives there, presumably he still uses his lab.  We don't know how far it is between James' house and the mansion, maybe he commutes between freaking out Cecilia and feeding the dog.  Or maybe he has persuaded his brother to help dog sitting.